# How to define list of Points for design-time data

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to perform design-time binding of `Polygon.Points` using `DesignData`? I tried the following:

**Polygon**

```
<Polygon Points="{Binding}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=./SamplePoints.xaml}">
```

**SamplePoints.xaml** (Build Action=DesignData, Custom Tool=MSBuild:Compile)

```
<media:PointCollection 
  xmlns:win="System.Windows"
  xmlns:media="System.Windows.Media">
  <win:Point X="10" Y="12"/>
  <win:Point X="21" Y="21" />
  <win:Point X="13" Y="14" />
  <win:Point X="41" Y="51" />
</media:PointCollection>
```

It doesn't recognize `PointCollection` and `Point` classes. I have ensured that `WindowBase` and `PresentationCore` are included in References. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to have this namespace defined: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` and then you can simply do `<PointCollection>10,12 21,21 13,14 41,51</PointCollection>` and `<Polygon Points="{Binding}"></Polygon>`. Of course, `PointCollection` belonging to your `DataContext`.

Comment: @jstreet: Thanks a bunch, that works. If you post that as an answer, I'll be glad to accept. I can also add `<Point X="10" Y="20" />` children into the `PointCollection` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication189"
        x:Class="WpfApplication189.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <PointCollection>250,50 450,300 50,300</PointCollection>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Polygon Points="{Binding}" Fill="Red"></Polygon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

You can also add points using `<Point X="10" Y="20" />` syntax under `<PointCollection>` node.